# Ormlite join on three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, ormlite

I want to create an inner join on three tables like this one for example:

```
Select m.* 
From MessageInbox mi 
   Inner Join Message m ON mi.MessageId = m.Id 
   Left Join Message m2 ON 
      m.ConversationStarterMessageId = m2.ConversationStarterMessageId 
      AND m.MessageSendDate < m2.MessageSendDate 
Where 
     m2.MessageSendDate IS NULL 
     AND mi.Deleted = 0 
     AND mi.RemovedFromInbox = 0 
     AND mi.UserId = ?userId 
Order By m.MessageSendDate DESC
```

How can I write this as an Ormlite query?

Comment: ok, and what is the problem? (on which actual tables?)

Comment: I want to ormlite query

Comment: How to create the above query to ormlite